# sql group by although there is not value

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a table where exists 4 entries like this.

```
class_type

id   type
1     A
2     B
3     M
4     T
```

and another table where these values are foreign key.

```
id   number id_class_type
1     10          1
2     11          1
3     12          2      
4     13          1
5     14          2
6     15          3
7     16          1
8     17          3
```

So what i want is count(*) and group by id_class_type but with all class_type (1,2,3,4) although there is not present the id 4.

Comment: Include the excepted result also as a text table..

Comment: Read about outer joins.

Answer (score 0):

if you want only the class tha match you can use inner join

```
  select a.class_type, count(*) 
  from class_type a
  inner join table2  b on a.id = b.id_class_type
  group by a.class_type
```

otherwise you can use left join

```
  select a.class_type, count(*) 
  from class_type a
  left join table2  b on a.id = b.id_class_type
  group by a.class_type
```